# No se están resaltando las etiquetas con diacríticos agregadas en ediciones sugeridas

Tags: bug, estado-completado, etiquetas, ediciones-sugeridas, interfaz-de-usuario

Recién estuve un rato tratando de entender de qué se trataba la edición sugerida en: https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/51233

Resulta que se agregó la etiqueta [matemáticas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matem%c3%a1ticas), pero se veía así:

[image: la etiqueta actual y la nueva sugerida se ven igual]

Cuando debería verse así:

[image: etiqueta resaltada en verde]

Le falta agregar el `<span class="diff-add">` para quedar:

```html
<a href="/questions/tagged/matem%c3%a1ticas" class="post-tag" title="" rel="tag"><span class="diff-add">matemáticas</span></a>
<!--                                                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ -->
```

---

Sólo sucede con **etiquetas con acentos**:

- <strike>En https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/51208 se agregó una etiqueta (y se editó el cuerpo), y sí se ve resaltada.</strike>
- <strike>No sé aún si es en ediciones sugeridas que sólo se agregan etiquetas, o si es un error relacionado al acento de la etiqueta.</strike>
- <strike>Acá hay otra edición del mismo usuario, que sólo modifica etiquetas, pero esta vez sin acentos se ven bien: https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/51156</strike>
- Una con, una sin. Sólo se resalta la etiqueta sin acentos:
  https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20105
- Modificación en cuerpo y etiqueta, sólo se resalta el cuerpo:
  https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18543
- No sucede en `/revisions`:
  https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/197/revisions
- Otros casos:

  - https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9816
  - https://spanish.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/12155
    ([reportado](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/empty-suggested-edit) por @fedorqui)
  - https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/116711
    (tampoco con `ç` o `ã`, como se ve en el [historial de revisiones](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/215105/revisions))

---

> - ¡¿A alguien se le ocurrió usar un regex con `\w+`?!

Comment: Me pasó lo mismo. De hecho lo reporté en Spanish: [Empty suggested edit?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2558/1674). La hipótesis que indicas de etiquetas con tildes parece la más probable.

Comment: Publicada también en [Diff highlighting fails on tags with diacritics in suggested edits reviews](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297660/304899)